# Where can I find the boot.ini file on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot.ini

Where is the `boot.ini` file in Windows 7?

Supposedly it's in the C: drive - I enabled hidden files and disabled *Hide system files* in the Folder Options but I still can't find it. Does anyone know where it is?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There isn't a boot.ini in Windows 7.  You can use `msconfig` to edit boot option however.

Windows 7/Vista has a hidden boot partition, containing the BCD - boot configuration data. Similar to boot.ini but you can't easily edit it like you can with notepad and XP. You can also [use the `bcdedit` tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Then what file does windows use to boot? if not boot.ini?

Comment: Windows 7/Vista has a hidden boot partition, containing the BCD - boot configuration data.  Similar to boot.ini but you can't easily edit it like you can with notepad and XP.  You can also use the bcdedit tool: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: Or try EasyBCD...http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1

Comment: To answer the literal question, the boot data is stored in a folder named \boot on the system partition.  In Windows 7, by default, the system partition does not have a drive letter assignment so you don't see it in Explorer.

Comment: (Note that Windows reverses the usual meanings of the phrase "boot partition" and "system partition"; the system partition contains the boot loader and the boot partition contains the system!)

Comment: What if we couldn't boot at all so we should edit the configs from out side like using a boot-able OS? in XP we could do it by editing boot.ini in windows 7 what we can do??